# Почему не ставится запятая? (2)

Tags: пунктуация

Чистятся огромные сапоги, подновляются непромокаемые, крашенные желтой масляной краской(,) плащи и кожаные штаны, штопаются паруса.

Answer (score 1):

***Чистятся огромные сапоги, подновляются непромокаемые, крашенные желтой масляной краской плащи и кожаные штаны, штопаются паруса.***

Судя по тексту диктанта, запятой там нет, то есть **причастный оборот не обособляется.**

В этом случае между прилагательным *непромокаемые* и оборотом *крашенные желтой масляной краской* **однородные отношения**. Однородность определяется причинно-следственной связью: непромокаемые, так как крашенные масляной краской.

**Примечание**

**В общем случае** обособление определительного оборота в такой позиции возможно (тогда он приобретает дополнительное пояснительное или уточняющее значение), но в данном предложении обособлять его не следует (оборот распространенный, обособлять его неудобно,  **уточняющего значения нет**).

**Примеры** с обособлением оборотов с уточняющим или пояснительным значением:

...чистые, **почти эллинского мрамора,** ступени монумента Аврааму Линкольну (Леонов). http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/46.htm

В его коллекции были и совсем старые, **датированные семнадцатым веком**, рукописи.

Comment: @Sharon **Правильное** (полное) предложение такое: _Чистятся рыбачьи сапоги, огромные до бедер сапоги из конской кожи, весом по полупуду каждый, подновляются непромокаемые, крашенные желтой масляной краской плащи и кожаные штаны, штопаются паруса, вяжутся переметы._ https://www.litres.ru/aleksandr-kuprin/beluga/chitat-onlayn/

Answer (score 0):

Может, я что-то не так понимаю, но, на мой взгляд, *определяемые слова* здесь ***плащи и кожаные штаны***, и они стоят ***после*** причастного оборота, поэтому запятая не нужна.

Comment: Артем, вот примеры из Розенталя: Пьер, с раннего утра уже стянутый в неловком, сделавшемся ему узким, дворянском мундире, был в залах (Л. Т.);  Их сопровождал небольшой плотненький человечек с флегматичным, почти заспанным, лицом (Т.); Здесь тоже два определения ПЕРЕД определяемым словом, но определительный оборот ОБОСОБЛЕН, так как имеет УТОЧНЯЮЩЕЕ значение  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118

Comment: Кстати, мне кажется, что определения относятся только к плащам, так как кожаные штаны вряд ли будут красить, они и так не промокают.

Comment: Ну да, можно рассмотреть и как уточнение, но можно же и иначе, нет? Согласен, да, видимо, только к плащам относится окраска. :)

Comment: Для двух определений перед определяемым словом возможны три варианта отношений: однородные, неоднородные, уточняющие. В каждом случае надо выбрать нужный вариант и обосновать его.  Я выбрала и обосновала однородные отношения, как и Вы. Но надо было дополнительно указать, что запятая ставится при уточняющих отношениях, а в этом случае уточнения НЕТ, поэтому нет и запятой.

Comment: Вы правы, Sharon, если б я был настолько подкован теорией и знал эти три вида, я бы так и сделал. Спасибо, что всё разложили по полочкам! Теперь буду понимать.